# How to turn tuple into string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

if

```
original = 'MK320MK180FM340SH230LL2HHH22TGF22',
```

Then I have stripped a string list such that looks like this (string --> tuple):

```
list = {('MK320',), ('MK180',), ('FM340',), ('SH230',), ('LL2',), ('HHH22',), ('TGF22',)}
```

I want to get rid of the comma inside the parentheses. That is, I want to make these tuples to be string back again. What I did was:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
''.join(list[i])
```

But it didn't get any better. Then I wanted to pass this to a different command, which is Counter. However, that actually included Counter{(blabla)}, which I didn't really like. What I wished to get a result as a dictionary, looking like this:

```
 {('MK320': 1, 'MK180': 1, 'FM340': 1, 'SH230': 1, 'LL2': 1, 'HHH22' : 1, 'TGF22': 1}
```

Which eventually counts the frequency of each product name.

Comment: A Counter is a dictionary. You access the keys no differently than a regular dict object

Comment: Please show the code that generated the tuples

Comment: And you can create a plain dictionary from a Counter by doing `dict(counter)`

Comment: Is it a list or a dict? It appears `list` is a dict in your code

Comment: what I am looking for is just to get rid of that ('dd,') form to just ' dd '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = [('MK320',), ('MK180',), ('FM340',), ('SH230',), ('LL2',), ('HHH22',), ('TGF22',)]
lst = [t[0] for t in lst]
```

Comment: That actually worked, but can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are converting your string to the `set` of `tuple` you are having. And, why are you even creating it when you don't need it?

You may use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module to get the desired list using the [`re.findall(pattern, string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re

>>> my_str = 'MK320MK180FM340SH230LL2HHH22TGF22'
>>> re.findall('[A-Za-z]+\d+', my_str)
['MK320', 'MK180', 'FM340', 'SH230', 'LL2', 'HHH22', 'TGF22']
```

Then, you may use [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the count. For example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> word_list = re.findall('[A-Za-z]+\d+', my_str)

>>> Counter(word_list)
Counter({'MK180': 1, 'SH230': 1, 'LL2': 1, 'FM340': 1, 'MK320': 1, 'TGF22': 1, 'HHH22': 1})
```

Comment: I am converting string to set of tuples then doing the same thing over again because the question asks me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Your `original` variable has a comma after it which makes it a tuple. If you want it to be a string, remove the trailing comma.

```
original = 'MK320MK180FM340SH230LL2HHH22TGF22'
```

You haven't shown how you generated the `list` variable. (Sidenote: don't name variables `list` or `str`, it shadows the built-in types.) But you can split this string into separate pieces like so:

```
import re

original = 'MK320MK180FM340SH230LL2HHH22TGF22'

split_list = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+\d+', original)
```

Your `list` variable is actually a set. The syntax for sets is `{item1, item2, item3}` while the syntax for lists is `[item1, item2, item3]`.

If you want to turn every tuple in this set into its first element:

```
new_list = [item[0] for item in list]
```

Finally, if you want to count the instances of each item in this list, you can pass it to `collections.Counter`.

```
import re
import collections

original = 'MK320MK180FM340SH230LL2HHH22TGF22'

split_list = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+\d+', original)

count = collections.Counter(split_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {('MK320',), ('MK180',), ('FM340',), ('SH230',), ('LL2',), ('HHH22',), ('TGF22',)}
```

That's a set rather than a list.

Please don't use `list` as a variable name, as there's already a very useful builtin function by that name. I'm going to pretend you named it `list1`.

It sounds like you want to hoist the elements out of the 1-tuples:

```
list2 = [elt for elt, in list1]
```

Then you could join it with `', '.join(list2)` as you wish.

Comment: Whats elt for elt supposed to mean? Python is still very very new for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a typo, or you doing something different from what you've described. Your `list` is actually a set of tuples. If that's what you meant to create then you can't use indexing as you've shown in your `for` loop. Given the desired output you're showing, it is also not really clear what you're going for as this is not valid syntax with the parenthesis after the curly brace.

The answer from @Moses-koledoye is the correct one given what you seem to want.

Comment: No it isn't exactly. Slicing in fives does not give the exact results they want.

Comment: Clearly you're right. Didn't realize they weren't all the same length.